# How to create a dynamic question within a streamlit form

Tags: python, streamlit

In a form, I want the second question to be a function of the answer to the first.

Here's a reproducible example. If they answer, 'Yes' to "Do you have data", they see a slider. If 'no', they get asked "why?". As it stands, the slider only dissapears after you hit submit.

```
import streamlit as st

with st.form("my_form"):
    st.write("Inside the form")
    checkbox_val = st.radio("Do you have data?", ("Yes", "No"), index=0)
    if checkbox_val == "Yes":
        slider_val = st.slider("Form slider")
    else:
        reason = st.radio("Reasons for no data", ("No time", "No interest"))

    # Every form must have a submit button.
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
    if submitted:
        st.write("slider", slider_val, "checkbox", checkbox_val, "reason", reason)

st.write("End of form")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Streamlit forms batch your input widgets, you will need to divide the form into multiple forms in order to achieve this functionality, or just use widgets outside of a form.

In other words, since the radio widget's value isn't being "sent" to Streamlit until the user hits "Submit", you won't be able to access the updated value of `checkbox_val` until the user submits the form.

e.g. if you want to do this without using a form:

```
placeholder = st.empty()
checkbox_val = st.radio("Do you want a slider or a radio?", ("Slider", "Radio"), index=0)
if checkbox_val == "Slider":
    slider_val = placeholder.slider("Form slider")
else:
    reason = placeholder.radio("Reasons for no data", ("No time", "No interest"))
```